# Reply functionality within cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, cloudpage

I have cloudpage set up which includes the form submission, after the form submission if the customer wants to reply back using the reply to address then it should be reaching out to a specific email address. I tried this by using custom RMM but seems like it is not working. Is there any code that I can apply within the cloudpage to get a get from the customer to a specific email ID either by using Javascript or Ampscript.

Please help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a customer to be able to send an email to a specific address. Could you use an old-fashioned mailto: link? It would open the user's default email program and autofill the recipient address, among other things: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/

You can add a mailto link in a form submission like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626940/mailto-on-submit-button